# i have to convert date from milliseconds value to normal with following style "14-Sep-2018 11:20:29:154 AM"

Tags: javascript, html, time

i want to display milli seconds value also. below is the code i used for getting output like "14-Sep-2018 11:20:29 AM" now i want to add milli seconds to this. how to proceed.

```
("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) +
"-" +
date.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "short" }) +
"-" +
(date.getFullYear() +
  " " +
  date.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
    second: "numeric",
    millisecond: "numeric",
    hour12: true
  }))
```

to the same stamp "14-Sep-2018 11:20:29 AM" after seconds i want milli seconds for same format.

Answer (score 0):

Using [getMilliseconds()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmilliseconds.asp)

```js
const d = new Date();

console.log(d.getMilliseconds());
```

Comment: if i get individually getdate getMin etc, they will be in 24Hr format but i need 12hrs format time with millisec and AM/PM

Comment: Why no just add milliseconds after your logic ? `date.toLocaleString`, your are already getting hours, minuste etc in h12 format (note: `millisecond: "numeric"`, doesn't exist)